# printk not working for kernel debgugging

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I put some debugging messages in the kernel code.
have checked /var/log/messages, dmesg and there is no such dump there.
syslogd is running on the machine

i also changed /proc/sys/kernel/printk to
8   4   1   7

any idea what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest explanation is your `printk()` is not being called.

Keep it simple and stick to checking `dmesg(1)` output while you're debugging this problem -- all the `syslog(3)` `/var/log/messages` and the console based output are separate from the issue of the messages not even showing up in the kernel's message buffer.

Comment: i placed prink() inside a core scheduler routine sched_fork(),normal_prio() et al.. none of them showed up in dmesg. can you suggest a routine which is always called in all the cases .just wanted to check my recompiled kernel is picked up when i have booted the machine

Comment: Wow, that's an expensive way to see into the scheduler. Look into `Documentation/scheduler/sched-stats.txt` for information on cheaper ways to learn what the scheduler is doing. :) If you want to see a changed kernel booted and working, I suggest modifying something more like `init/main.c`'s `start_kernel()` function. It kicks awake all the different subsystems at boot.

Comment: thanks for the comment.. Looks like my way was way expensive Documentation/scheduler is much nicer way to learn it. somehow i am skeptical that my recompiled kernel which i installed through dpkg -i is not active. how to verify this? i have succefully rebooted the machine and followed everything step by step mentioned in http://blog.avirtualhome.com/2010/11/06/how-to-compile-a-ubuntu-10-10-maverick-kernel/

Comment: Check the build date of `uname -a` in your running kernel -- it'll give you a better idea if you're on a kernel you built today or if you're on a distribution-provided kernel. While those instructions you found look great for following the Ubuntu kernel development, it feels a little "heavy" -- if you don't mind using the upstream kernel.org kernel instead, look into [kernel-package](http://packages.debian.org/sid/kernel-package) (also available in some of the Ubuntu repositories) -- it's far easier to work with.

Comment: thanks for the help. Can you suggest me any lightweight easy to build kernel. i want to do some work on scheduler modification. I am newbie to kernel development.

Comment: Modern Linux is definitely harder to modify than it used to be. The 2.2 Linux kernel was a lot easier to modify and play with; if you boot it into KVM or something similar, its significantly older hardware support won't be much of an issue. A fellow stacker was asking questions about the toy os [OS/161](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~syrah/os161/) the other day -- it looks cool, but might leave too much to you to implement. I haven't really looked at any of the BSD kernels since OpenBSD 3.3 or FreeBSD 4.0, but both those were very straight-forward build and modification environments.

Comment: **BUT**, I think if you look into the `kernel-package` package, you'll find building and installing new Linux kernels isn't as much work as your `avirtualhome.com` instructions would indicate.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem until yesterday, when i found something interesting. Lately linux kernel has been adopting pr_**** instead of printk (3.5 version and later).

I have tried running a basic module program with printk on 3.3 version of the kernel & the same on 3.7 and above.

Former works fine. Later just doesn't show up the printk's on dmesg or `/var/log/messages`. However **replacing the printk with pr_info macro,did the job.** (other variants are also there pr_err, pr_notice etc found in *include/linux/kernel.h* earlier now moved to *include/linux/printk.h*)

Although, pr_**** macro's are quite old, thanks to campaign by Joe Perches, who has initiated the above mentioned change, we better learn the kernel ways ! 
(Reference: [pr_info()](http://lwn.net/Articles/487437/))