# Is printk() deprecated?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, printk

Asking this seems absurd to me but...

I'm reading [Linux Device Drivers](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) to learn how to create kernel modules. The book seems a bit old but I couldn't find a more recent version.

So I set up a Debian 12 virtual machine with VirtualBox, cloned the Linux kernel v6.4.3, recompiled and installed it.

Finally, in a different folder, I wrote the book's first simple "hello world" example which I show at the end of this question. It uses `printk()` to print a warning message in init and one in exit.
Doing:

```sh
insmod hello.ko
```

Prints an empty line in my `dmesg` buffer, as shown in image below. Same for `rmmod` command. So I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090944/printk-not-working-for-kernel-debgugging) and decided to change my

```c
printk(KERNEL_WARNING, "Hello, World!\n")
```

to

```c
pr_err("Hello, world!\n")
```

and now I have a decent line shown in dmesg. Am I doing something wrong? What is wrong with using `printk()`?

Code and image below:

```c
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("Duas BSD/GPL");

static int hello_init(void)
{
    // pr_err("Hello, world!\n"); // uncomment this line to get intended result
    printk(KERN_ERR, "Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}

static void hello_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ERR, "Goodbye, world!\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

`dmesg` result below. Blank spaces in dmesg result are generated by `insmod hello.ko` compiled with `pr_err()` line commented. "Hello world" line was generated by uncommenting `pr_err()` line.

[image]

Comment: Looking at info [here](https://elinux.org/Debugging_by_printing), `Note that there is NO comma between the KERN_ERR and the format string`, if that might make the difference?

Comment: Yes! It was exactly the comma that was causing the weird behavior.
Thanks!